# How To Get State of Switch If No Match in React ReactRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using the ReactRouter and want to do something like set state when the RouteNotFound component is hit (last one means no others above matched).

my `this.handler` does a setState so that I can tell that it was called. That of course gives me an error saying "Cannot update during an existing state transition such as in a render".

Is there a way I can set my state to tell me which (I really want to know the last one) of the switch statements go executed?

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/p1" component={p1}/>
                <Route exact path="/p2" component={p2}/>
                <RouteNotFound action={this.handler} ></RouteNotFound>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: What you are looking for is the onEnter functionality of react-router which in react-router-v4 can be acieved through lifecycle methods. Check the duplicate question for implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we go:

**not-found.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const RouteNoteFound = ({ action }) => (
  <Route
    render={props => (
      <NotFoundPageComponent action={action} />
    )}
  />
);


export default RouteNoteFound;

class NotFoundPageComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.action()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>404 not found</div>
    )
  }
}
```

and in **index.js:**

```
handler = () => {
    alert("alert from app.js but run in not found page")
}

render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Page} />
          <Route path="/page" component={Page} />
          <RouteNoteFound action={this.handler} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

---

here is [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8odysp) in stackblitz.

Comment: in index.js, I want to push that "state" up to its parent and then again up to its parent.  I think I want to set state in the action handler and then in ComponentDidUpdate, send the state up to parent. When I do that I get into recursion problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Define the not found route like this:

```
<Route render={props => <RouteNotFound action={this.handler} />}></Route>
```

Because, as per the **[Doc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch/Switch-props)**:

> A `<Route>` with no path prop or a `<Redirect>` with no from prop will
>   always match the current location.

Check the **[Doc example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match)** for "No Path Match".

Now use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method in RouteNotFound component, whenever RouteNotFound will get rendered, `componentDidMount` will be called. Call the parent function from `componentDidMount`, like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.props.action();
}
```

Now do setState inside `action` in parent component.

Comment: The problem still exists in {this.handler}. I gather I can not do a state update inside the render function. Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

Comment: what are you expection is in the {this.handler}. I've got the setState(...) in that which is causing the error I listed in the previous comment

Comment: not sure, why it is throwing error, are you using `()` with `this.handler` ? because it should work. It is working when doing setState inside `componentWillMount`?